# How to check if stm32 is working?

Tags: arduino, embedded, usb, stm32

I have an STM32F03 and soldered it. How to check if all solders are correct and the device is working? (I didn't burn a bootloader and I don't have stlink).

Another question can I use an Arduino UNO (CG340G` clone) to program the STM32F1?

Comment: "Soldered it" to what? To have built a board with a chip that complex without having the first idea how to program it might be considered foolhardy.

Comment: I soldered pin headers to board that includes stm32 and crystal with other things.

Comment: That makes more sense but that is not what your question suggests, and is hardly relevant in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STM32 has a bootloader in on-chip ROM which runs on start-up if you have asserted the boot configuration pins to do that. It is capable of loading code to Flash memory via USART1 on STM32F1xxx.

It is no doubt possible to implement a JTAG or SWI debug/programmer adapter using an Arduino UNO. JTAG itself is very simple to implement, and using OpenOCD on the PC it would be possible to drive the adapter.  It would be simplest to do that if you were to emulate or clone an existing adapter already supported by OpenOCD.  For example [JTAGduino](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/jtagduino-jtag-connection-using-arduino/).

Answer (score 0):

1. To check soldering is best practice to use special testing program which must by started from MCU (flashed or from RAM using JTAG/SWD) but if you can't flash or use ST-link, then no idea, because all GPIOs are in high impedance, then you have no way how to detect correct soldering on GPIOs.
2. Yes, you can use Arduino or any other MCU to program STM32F1, you have two possibilities:

   - using SWD
   - using boot-loader which is included in MCU http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00167594.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else.  I dont think there is an external sign of life on that chip (running out to read a flash, etc that you might find on a chip that relies on off chip rom/ram).

So ...read the manual...

it tells about the boot strap pins and what they do, and there are other documents and examples (I have a number of them "out there") that show you how to use the uart to connect to the bootloader if you have strapped it right.

I also agree that it really makes no sense to be soldering a part down if you have not read up on the pinout and the boot modes.  did you even check to see if you needed an external oscillator or crystal or other components?  One of the many things you need to do first.  Now i can understand if you are on some team and the "hardware folks" did their thing and tossed this board over the wall to you to do your thing, I get that, that unfortunately happens all too often.  You should have known the board was coming, well before the board was finalized, you should have been in the decision tree for what part to use, and you should have driven the hardware folks as to what options you needed them to implement (a reset button, or a boot0 or boot1 button or jumpers, the default strapping you wanted for that boot0 button, etc).  All of these things should happen before the pcb is made and certainly well before solder starts to flow.

Spend the $10 and get one of the discovery or other boards with an stlink on it.  spend another $10-$15 for an ftdi breakout board that you can use to connect the uart.  between those you should be able to talk to the chip and see if it is alive, also you can use an st discovery or other board to try the serial bootloader and write the few lines of code to initiate contact with the bootloader and see it respond, then go try the same thing on your board.

Comment: I just happened to have recently bought a handful of stm32f0 parts and soldered them to a breakout board.  the st bootloader was already in these parts, wasnt something I had to add.